# Need performance in R - "which" seems to be too long

Tags: r, performance

Here is my dataframe:

```
b<-data.frame(SEQUENCEID=c("0","1","1","1","2","2"),
              EVENTID=c("1","1","1","2","1","2"),
              ITEM=c("z","a","b","a","c","a"))

  SEQUENCEID EVENTID ITEM
1          0       1    z
2          1       1    a
3          1       1    b
4          1       2    a
5          2       1    c
6          2       2    a
```

I need to put items associated to a unique combo [SEQUENCEID;EVENTID] into an element of a list so that I want my final result to look like this:

```
$`1`          
       "0"        "1"        "z" 

$`2`                    
       "1"        "1"        "a"        "b" 

$`3`          
       "1"        "2"        "a" 

$`4`          
       "2"        "1"        "c"
```

Actually I know how to do it, my problem is that it takes too much time since I have about 1 million rows in my `data.frame`. Here is the script to do it:

```
#STEP 1
b$combi=as.character(paste(b$SEQUENCEID,b$EVENTID,sep="|"))
combi_unique=unique(b$combi)
stock=sapply(combi_unique,function(x) b$ITEM[which(b$combi==x)])
names(stock)=NULL

#STEP 2
r=as.list(as.data.frame(t(unique(b[,c("SEQUENCEID","EVENTID")]))))

#STEP 3
results=mapply(c, r, stock, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

How would you re-code this to make it work faster?

Comment: Going by your sample data.frame `b`, shouldn't the first list component in your expected output be `0 1 z` rather than `1 2 z`?

Comment: Are duplicate ITEM values for a pair of SID/EID possible? e.g. `[1, 1, a, b, a]`

Comment: Yeah duplicate values might be possible
But I would be interested in case you have something powerful with no duplicate values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do that with a combination of tidyr and dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
b = data_frame(
  SEQUENCEID = c("0","1","1","1","2","2"),
  EVENTID = c("1","1","1","2","1","2"),
  ITEM = c("z","a","b","a","c","a")
)    

final = b %>% 
  group_by(SEQUENCEID, EVENTID) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  lapply(identity)
```

**Benchmark**

I simulated a bigger data-frame with your same structure: 10^7 rows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
b = data_frame(
   SEQUENCEID = sample(1:10, 10^7, replace = T),
   EVENTID = sample(1:10, 10^7, replace = T),
   ITEM = sample(letters, 10^7, replace = T)
)
```

and the code runs in around 3 secs on my Mac:

```
system.time({
  final = b %>% 
    group_by(SEQUENCEID, EVENTID) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    lapply(identity)
})
```

for a 10^8 dataset it took a bit more: 44 secs

Comment: thanks for your answer but Dplyr is known to be not really efficient on big dataset

Comment: No. dplyr is known to be very fast. I simulated a 10^7 data-frame similar to yours and my code runs in 3secs. I'll update my code with this benchmark now

Comment: My bad, it's true. I did not know this data_frame function

Answer (score 1):

try

```
split(b$ITEM, with(b, interaction(SEQUENCEID, EVENTID)))
```

### or to format it exactly as you asked:

```
b<-data.frame(SEQUENCEID=c("0","1","1","1","2","2"),
              EVENTID=c("1","1","1","2","1","2"),
              ITEM=c("z","a","b","a","c","a"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# ensure stringsAsFactors=FALSE; in your big data frame this would ..
# ... translate as if(is.factor(b$ITEM)) b$ITEM<-as.character(b$ITEM)
bs <- split(b, with(b, interaction(SEQUENCEID, EVENTID)))

# get rid of empty elements:
bs <- bs[sapply(ns, NROW)>0]

lapply(bs, function(x) with(x,c(SEQUENCEID[1], EVENTID[1], ITEM)))
# alternatively:
lapply(bs, function(x) with(x,c(SEQUENCEID=SEQUENCEID[1], EVENTID=EVENTID[1], ITEM)))
```

.. I suppose there would be a data.table solution that would be faster

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I run it, my 4th element of my list is empty and I do not want it.
[[4]]
factor(0)
Levels: a b c z

Comment: Well it seems it did not work. I got this error message : Reached total allocation of 8066Mb: see help(memory.size)